# When i tried to init react-native project getting Error : npm ERR

Tags: react-native

```
npx react-native init MobApp
Need to install the following packages:
react-native
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/saadbawany/.npm/\_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/browserslist
npm ERR! dest /Users/saadbawany/.npm/\_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/.browserslist-jjYG0t4x
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/saadbawany/.npm/\_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/browserslist' -\> '/Users/saadbawany/.npm/\_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/.browserslist-jjYG0t4x'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/saadbawany/.npm/\_logs/2022-04-03T22_24_15_101Z-debug-0.log
```

Already tried deleting node and re-installing
MacOS Monterey
node version v16.14.2
also tried initing react native 0.67